# Pre-populate formset with a user saved data on revisit

Tags: python, django, formset

I need to pre-populate a formset field with a user's saved data

Here is my form.py

```
EssayQuestionFormSetBase = modelformset_factory(models.EssayQuestion,
                                            extra=0,
                                            fields=('prompt',),
                                             widgets={
                                                 'prompt': forms.TextInput(
                                                     attrs={'readonly': True, 'class': 'borderless'}),
                                             },
                                            )

class EssayQuestionFormSet(EssayQuestionFormSetBase):
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super(EssayQuestionFormSet, self).add_fields(form, index)
        form.fields['answer'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='')
```

As you can see, I added a field to accept answers in the EssayQuestionFormSet

My views.py looks like following:

```
class QuizDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):

        step = models.Quiz.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['step_pk'])

        eqs = models.EssayQuestion.objects.filter(quiz_id=self.kwargs['step_pk'])
        eqs_formset = forms.EssayQuestionFormSet(queryset=eqs, prefix='essay')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        step = models.Quiz.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['step_pk'])   

        eqs = models.EssayQuestion.objects.filter(quiz_id=self.kwargs['step_pk'])
        eqs_formset = forms.EssayQuestionFormSet(request.POST, queryset=eqs, prefix='essay')


        if eqs_formset.is_valid():
            for form in eqs_formset:
                # create a NEW Answer for this form's associated question
                new_answer = models.Answer.objects.create(question=form.instance,
                                                          eq_answer_text=form.cleaned_data.get('answer'),
                                                          student=models.Student.objects.get(user=request.user.pk))
```

Currently, the view properly renders empty Textarea field for the answer field on the get and properly saves answers on the post. My question, however, **how can I pre-populate the answer field with user's saved answers?**

Here is the Answer model

```
class Answer(models.Model):
    date_answered = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, blank=True, null=True, related_name='answers')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    eq_answer_text = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
```

Comment: I'm not sure formsets are the appropriate solution here at all. You're not trying to create or edit essay questions, you're trying to create/update one answer per question.

Comment: what would be the appropriate solution? sorry I just started to learn Django

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can do that by passing initials.Left hand side value names should be same to the form fields in which you want to populate your data.

```
initial = {
'question' :answer.question,
'answer':answer.answer,
}
form = AnswerForm(initial=initial)
```

Comment: I have tried as you advised, no luck. By some reasons initial does not come to formset as initial, but as initial_extra

Comment: It seems like initial does not work the same way with model formset as it works with  regular formset  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#id2